# What makes a 3D game's graphics

Tags: graphics, 3d, xna, shader, modeling

As a somewhat experienced XNA developer, and a beginner to the world of 3D modeling (via Autodesk Maya), I was really wondering what actually makes the graphics look so good in video games such as Crysis3, FarCry3, Metro:Last Light, etc..

Are the game's graphics affected mostly by the Models? Shaders? Something withing the game's engine? Or might it even be the textures that are used?

My guess was that the game's shaders are the most important, but since I barely know anything about it I've decided to ask before I start learning how to program it (HLSL, right?).

thanks.

Comment: Ask this on the gamedevelopment site of SE to be on topic. Anyway, i have seen bad models become great with the right texture and good models look dull with a bad texture. The texture makes the most difference but when all 3 done great you stick out from the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's the artists.** A good artist can take anything and make it look beautiful.

It really comes down to a combination of things - the models, the shaders, the textures. The [dirty tricks](http://simonschreibt.blogspot.de/p/more-game-art-tricks.html) you use to combine these things.

But I think, from the perspective you're asking your question from, the answer is definitely "the shaders". The shaders are what bring everything together to create the final image. Shaders are basically little programs - so they can do more-or-less anything.

Of course, that's kind of like asking "what makes software so great?" and saying that it's "the code".

**Probably the most important thing that makes a 3D scene look realistic/good is the lighting.** This is usually done in shaders. But it could also be pre-calculated and stored in textures. Or some combination of the two.

[Here's an article](http://www.fxguide.com/featured/game-environments-parta-remember-me-rendering/) about a game that has an advanced, physically-accurate lighting simulation (many games are still using non-physical simulations). The shader is what does the lighting calculation itself - but the textures that define a material's properties are obviously integral to this process.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! 
It's just that I'm really interested in this aspect of game development, but have absolutely no idea where should I start. 
(Should i Keep using XNA..? HLSL or GLSL..? How does everything cooperates with the actual coding..? and so on..)

Comment: Perhaps stick with XNA while you're learning. It's easy to get started and it has some [great samples](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/?contenttype=0&devarea=14&platform=0&sort=1). I think the [sprite effects](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/sprite_effects) sample is perhaps the simplest to start with. The shader series is also a good introduction. But try all of them. XNA (because it's based on DirectX) uses HLSL as its shading language. OpenGL uses GLSL, although the basic concepts are the same.